# Changing Fragment From within another Fragment Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, illegalstateexception

I'm working with fragments and I've encountered an exception when trying to change the fragment from current fragment.
The basic design is:

1. An activity with a frame layout.
2. Fragment A that is initially placed in the frame layout of activity.
3. Fragment A layout has a frame layout lets say frame_layout_a.
4. Child_Fragment_A that is initially loaded in frame_layout_a.

The main design idea is to press a button Child_Fragment_A that loads Child_Fragment_B in the frame_layout_a.
Currently in the On Click Listener for the button in Child_Fragment_A, I'm using the following code for this purpose

```
if (v.getParent() != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, new searchResults());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            Log.d("mActivity", "loadfragment()");
        }
        else{
            ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment, new searchResults());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            Log.d("mActivity", "loadfragment()");
        }
```

This onClick() is implemented in the OnCreateView of Child_Fragment_A. However, this leads to the following exception:

**Exception**

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rehnsehan, PID: 2114
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Hopefully I was able to explain my problem sufficiently, Kindly point out what I'm missing or doing wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace

Comment: @ianhanniballake added it in an edit